# How to call web address from MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to call web address from tsql. It needs to be simple and lightweight. Nothing is returned from web call and is not procesed.

I have found some ways using CLR and OA methods, but I am looking for something simpler because Server is not supposed to do anything afrer calling web address.

Comment: That's generally a horrible idea.  You should rethink your design.

Comment: Being unsure of what it means to "call a web address" (BR549, ring 2?), I'll suggest that you toss the URL into an MSMQ message queue and let an application suck it out and drop the dime. Since you want it to be asynchronous and transmitting in the blind relative to SQL Server that should be just fine.

Comment: @SLaks I generally agree. In thia case I want to get notified when SQL table is updated. It is updated by propriatery Windows programm. I don't have access to source xode, but have access to SQL. That is why I considered calling http address in local network as a way of notification that data is changed. Orher oprion would be to query table periodically but then I would need to build system to tell previous data from new data.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx

Comment: Its a bad idea, but you could make code your own program and call it with xp_cmdshell. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx